# Avoid stopping nginx while renewing a certificate of letsencrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a task in cron:

```
  sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot renew --quiet
```

It fails. After I stop nginx and re-run the command, it succeeds. Then I have to start nginx again.

I don't want to have to stop it, though, because the cron task is executed once a day, automatically and stopping nginx will make my website unavailable. How to avoid stopping nginx?

Comment: Please, provide more information. Have you tried to forward stderr,stdout to a file? sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot renew --quiet >> /tmp/output.log. Why do you use restart instead of reload, etc..

Comment: What is the reason it fails - we would need to know this to help provide an answer

Comment: Yep. What's the error message? Any guide on nginx + certbot mention that the bot merely updates the cert files in place and then nginx is reloaded (not restarted) to re-read these files among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: it's the same thing: stop and start

Comment: It doesn't pull the process / and site down with reload

Comment: then certbot won't work!